# AWS Server RDP Connection Authentication Error

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a AWS Server running Windows 2012R2. Today I changed 2 group policy settings i.e.

1. Accounts: Limit local account use of blank passwords to console login only - disabled
2. Network access: sharing and security model for local accounts (Guest only)

After I restarted the server I am unable to connect to the server using RDP. This happened because of the group policy settings that I changed. How to fix it as I can't connect via RDP? When I try to connect it gives error:
"An Authentication Error has occured. The local security authority cannot be contacted.
This could be due to expired passwords. Please update your password if it has expired."
Please help as its urgent. Thank you

Comment: `This happened because of the group policy settings that I changed.` really? How is that?